# inner panel height not 100% on overflow

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a panel with components inside and once the submit button is pressed, an overlay appears, but is not covering the entire parent panel (see picture) when I have scrolled all the way to the bottom. Also, the spinner need to be always in the center whether I am scrolling or not. I used `position: fixed;` but I don't know if that's the best practice.

**CSS**

```
.pay-storage-container {
  $inner-padding: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 325px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #fff;

     .loading-container {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        img {
          position: fixed;
          top: 50%;
          right: 18%;
          animation: spinner 1s linear infinite;
        }
      }
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pay-storage-container {{toggleSideBar ? 'showSideBar' : 'closeSideBar'}}">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">Pay Storage</div>
    <span class='close-icon csx-common_delete' (click)="onToggleSideBar(false)"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pay-storage-inner">
    <app-equipment-summary [equipmentSummary]='equipmentSummary'></app-equipment-summary>
    <app-credit-card #creditCardForm></app-credit-card>
    <div class="loading-container" *ngIf="isLoading">
      <img src="assets/spinner.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <!-- <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" [disabled]='!creditCardForm.creditCardForm.valid || isLoading'
      (click)="onSubmitPayment()"></button> -->
    <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" [disabled]='isLoading' (click)="onSubmitPayment()"></button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="paymentMessage$ | async as message" class="pay-storage-inner pay-storage-success">
    <app-payment-success [paymentSuccess]="paymentSuccess" (close)="onToggleSideBar($event)"></app-payment-success>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should use position fixed for loading-container with top: 0 and left: 0

Comment: ...add right: 0, bottom: 0 to dnp1204's comment you should have your fix.

Comment: this doesn't put the spinner in the center. It put the spinner on the top left of the entire page. Any suggestions for the overlay to be the height:100% of the parent even on the scroll? @dnp1204

Comment: @TamoDev the way you're currently centering your spinner would be inconsistent between devices anyway. Google 'centering div css' for css tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is anything wrong with using position:fixed to keep your spinner in the center of the page.

Also, if you want to fully overlay your content then your loading-container needs to be at the very bottom of the content you want overlayed. This code below should just overlay pay-storage-container:

```
<div class="pay-storage-container {{toggleSideBar ? 'showSideBar' : 'closeSideBar'}}">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">Pay Storage</div>
    <span class='close-icon csx-common_delete' (click)="onToggleSideBar(false)"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pay-storage-inner">
    <app-equipment-summary [equipmentSummary]='equipmentSummary'></app-equipment-summary>
    <app-credit-card #creditCardForm></app-credit-card>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <!-- <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" [disabled]='!creditCardForm.creditCardForm.valid || isLoading'
      (click)="onSubmitPayment()"></button> -->
    <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" [disabled]='isLoading' (click)="onSubmitPayment()"></button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="paymentMessage$ | async as message" class="pay-storage-inner pay-storage-success">
    <app-payment-success [paymentSuccess]="paymentSuccess" (close)="onToggleSideBar($event)"></app-payment-success>
  </div>
    <div class="loading-container" *ngIf="isLoading">
      <img src="assets/spinner.svg" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a sample code snippet which centers overlay spinner for all dimensions. You can edit your CSS accordingly to achieve centered spinner with overlay.

```css
/* Absolute Center Spinner */

.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/* Transparent Overlay */

.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */

.loading:not(:required) {
  /* hide "loading..." text */
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.loading:not(:required):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}


/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
```

`